# Toner ended error on a brother 2370DN printer

Tags: printer, brother-printer

I have a Brother HL-L2370DN in which the toner has ran out of ink. I refilled the toner cartridge with ink, but when I reinstalled it in the printer, it said toner ended. Multiple YT tutorials has suggested toner reset through the following steps:

1. I opened the cover and pressed the Go and back button and then the back button fast so I get the options: `TNR-STR`, `TNR-HC`, `TNR-STD`, `TNR.S-HC`.
2. I pressed OK on the `TNR-HC` as the tutorials suggested. No luck
3. I even tried the other options arbitrarily. They did not work.

Other tutorials suggested manual reset through user mode in which I did the following:

1. I shut down the printer
2. I pressed both the ON and Go button till I got the user mode in the small LCD screen
3. I then pressed the GO button 9 times till the network light flashed
4. Finally I pressed the GO button again 5 times till the network light flashed again.

All these attempts was unfruitful, the toner works fine after refilling on another printer of the same model. The toner number is TN2405, the drum number is DR-2405. Thank you for the help.